# Auto selecting files in QTreeView with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt

I'm using a `QTreeView` with `QFileSystemModel` and `QSortFilterProxyModel`. My goal is to pre-select certain files for the user using the treeviews `keyboardSearch` method.

QFileSystemModel offers the signal `directoryLoaded` to let me know when i can select the files. This works fine on its own but fails in combination with the QSortFilterProxy. The signal seems to be fired before the sorting and keyBoardSearch fails.

Is there a way to add a similar signal to QSortFilterProxy? Or maybe another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QFileSystem offers the `layoutChanged` signal that is emitted after QSortFilterProxy sorts the items.